# Why does "throw Error" make a function run as synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I was writing some code and found something interesting.

Example 1:

```
async function load(closure) {
    try {
      await closure();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error");
    } finally {
      console.log("finished");
    }
  }

  load(async () => {
    throw new Error();
  });

  console.log("hello");
```

This outputs:

```
hello
error
finished
```

However, if I call:

Example 2:

```
load(() => {
  throw new Error();
});
```

The output is:

```
error
finished
hello
```

Can you explain what's going on here?

I understand that calling `await` queues execution to the next tick, so the first output is expected.

But in the second example, why is `closure` behaving as a synchronous function if the caller is using `await`?

This only happens when there's an `Error` thrown. If I call...

Example 3:

```
load(() => {
    return 1;
});
```

... then `closure` is called in the next tick as expected.

Comment: Declaring a function `async` wraps its body in a Promise, and turns `throw` into a call to `reject()`.

Comment: `await` doesn't do anything special if its argument isn't a Promise, it simply returns that value.

Comment: yup, I understand that. The issue I was having is that in the last example (`return 1`), even though `closure` is not `async`, the output is like in the original example (`async`). But when I throw an Error, then everything becomes synchronous.

Comment: You're calling `closure()` synchronously and it's throwing synchronously.  This is identical in concept to putting `throw new Error("Some Error")` before your call to `closure()`.

Comment: `closure` is always called asynchronously because of the `await`, but yes, we deduced that the `new Error()` is being thrown before the necessary promise is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#description)

> The expression is resolved in the same way as Promise.resolve(): it's always converted to a native Promise and then awaited

In your `Example 2`, `await` is not used because the error happens before the creation of the promise (i.e. during the execution of the `closure` function). The function doesn't return any value so there is no conversion to a native Promise.

- If `closure()` is not `async` and throws an exception, the promise has not a chance to be created, that's why you see `error` and `finished` logs first. In fact `await` has not been used since `closure` function has not been fully executed.
- If `closure()` is not `async` and returns a value, it's converted to a promise and the async function pauses until the next tick, that's why you see `hello` first.
- If `closure()` is not `async` and returns a rejected promise like `Promise.rejected()`, you will see `hello` first because `await` received a rejected promise and the async function pauses until the next tick like before.

```js
function fn() {
  throw new Error();
}

async function load() {
  try {
    await fn(); // like await Promise.resolve(fn())
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("
        I came here because an error occurred during fn execution.
        No promise has been created and await has not been used.
        The async function has not been paused.
    ");
  }
}
```

```js
function fn() {
  return Promise.reject("error");
}
// same as
async function fn() {
  throw "error";
}

async function load() {
  try {
    await fn(); // like await Promise.reject()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("
        I came here because await received a rejected promise.
        The async function has been paused until the next tick.
    ");
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first example, the function is converted to a promise because of the `async`. You can call `closure().then()` with no problem. It's just a rejected promised.

Comment: calling an async function doesn't mean it's not executed immediately. When you call an async function, the function is executed and maybe paused if there is an await.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted because your statement `No promise has been created and await has not been used.` answers the question.

Comment: The reason why it runs like synchronous is because the `throw` makes it impossible for the promise to be created. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, sorry, I was referring to the first example in the original question which creates a `Promise` because of the `async`. The `fn` function in your first example, however, doesn't create a `Promise` because it's not `async` and throws an error before creating the promise needed by `await cb()`. All clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two examples is due to the fact that the `async/await` syntax introduces an implicit delay in the function execution that causes the `finally` block to execute after the `console.log("hello")` statement.

Comment: the first paragraph is correct but the second is not: when you call example 3 (see question edit), there is a delay even though the `closure` function is synchronous. But if I throw an `Error` it works as if there was not `await` at all (everything is synchronous).